# Using Search API to create an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am planning to create an Angular 1 support for VScode, because we use angular 1 in a legacy application. I would need to search files containing a certain pattern. I would like to use VScode internal API that is being used while we search in files in VScode. There is an extension that does the similar thing but uses a node module to search with in project [Fuzzy Definitions].

But it would be great to use the native API. I search the api doc https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api. Could not find such API there.

Answer (score 0):

The current API does not support this but there is ongoing work (as of August 2017) to expand the search API which may include the features you are asking for. I encourage you to enter the discussion with your use case.

The issue tracking this is [issue 29194](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/29194), though the main user story is enabling remote development, so it is unclear whether they intend to add the search capabilities to the extension API.

> Remote development describes a setup in which VS Code is used to edit
>   files that reside on a different computer which file system cannot be
>   mounted. A server that only offers FTP is an example of such a setup.
>
> The following features should be supported for good dev experience
>
> - see resources in the explorer, either as separate view or inline with the open folder/folders
> - open (text) files, modify, save, and revert them. Lots of thoughts about this have been written down in #10547 (comment) and #29025
> - support file events from the remote source being reflected in the editor, e.g. update explorer, close editors, invalidate search caches
>     etc.
> - allow to search for files by their name in the same way we do it today using Cmd+P
> - allow to search inside files, again merging with the existing search experience.
> - think about language services/servers which today usually rely on having disk-access to files
>
> The goal is to enable remote development via extensions, so new
>   provider APIs are required to allow 3rd parties to integrate into more
>   pieces of our system. Similar to #29025 we start with assessing how
>   many assumptions are backed into our system and how we can make it
>   aware of having multiple sources of truth, e.g. multiple search result
>   providers, etc, etc.

The work in progress can be found in [PR 32549](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/32549)